# Unity: How to stretch UI picture to relative size of canvas without it overstretching?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, graphics

My UI elements in free-aspect ratio screen are perfect but when I change aspect ratios the text and pictures are way too small. I'm using an anchor to the corners for the UI elements; however, if I use the all-direction stretch then it overstretches. How do I prevent overstretching? I want the image to stretch relative to the canvas size while being anchored in a position. How do I do this?

[image: original; small screen]

[image: small UI; increased ratio screen]

Answer (score 2):

First, You need to create an empty `GameObject`. This object needs to be a child of your canvas. Inside this empty object you'll put all of your GUI objects (Images, Buttons, etc...)

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCBCd.png)

Next, set the anchor preset to strecth [As here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUmP0.png)

Then you need to write this [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q4hw.png) (don't forget * 1f after Scale.width and height because if you don't write this the operation Scale.width / Scale.height will be considered as an integer and not a float)

Finally, use these [Canvas Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjV78.png)

Answer (score 1):

If the anchors are set properly then it is most likely the `Canvas Scaler` needs to be changed to "Scale with Screen Size" mode so that it changes to the resolution you put in i.e. X:800, Y:600. If this still doesn't work then you should change text Paragraph to "Best Fit".